# Running tagged ScalaTest tests in Gradle

Tags: gradle, scalatest

ScalaTest has such a feature as [tagging](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/tagging_your_tests)  different tests. It would be great somehow to instruct gradle about what type of tests it should run while executing `test` task(as it [done](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin) in scalatest maven-plugin). How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

As Gradle doesn't have any specific ScalaTest support, the question is if ScalaTest exposes this feature in a JUnit-compatible way. Alternatively, you could leverage Gradle's support for JUnit categories (see "23.12.5. Test grouping" in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html)).